# Generate string from integer with arbitrary base in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, string

In JavaScript you can generate a string from a number like this:

```
(123).toString(36) // => "3f"
```

If you try to do arbitrary base:

```
(123).toString(40)
```

You get

```
Uncaught RangeError: toString() radix argument must be between 2 and 36
    at Number.toString (<anonymous>)
    at <anonymous>:1:7
```

Wondering how to do this to generate a string given an arbitrary alphabet. So say you have this alphabet:

```
abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-
```

Then it would be like:

```
toString(123, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-')
```

And it would print something out (I have no idea what) such as `3+`, picking from the alphabet.

Wondering how to do this in JavaScript, not sure if the "radix" has anything to do with it. Thank you.

**Update**: Looking how to reverse it as well, aka `fromString(string)`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

While you asked for a `parseInt` for an arbitrary length, you could use the given string and reduce it by multiplying the former reduce value with the code length and adding the numerical value of the position of the code character.

Additional is the `toString` function supplied.

```js
function parseInt(value, code) {
    return [...value].reduce((r, a) => r * code.length + code.indexOf(a), 0);
}

function toString(value, code) {
    var digit,
        radix= code.length,
        result = '';

    do {
        digit = value % radix;
        result = code[digit] + result;
        value = Math.floor(value / radix);
    } while (value)

    return result;
}

console.log(parseInt('dj', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(toString(123, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(parseInt('a', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(toString(0, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0; }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can simulate that doing:

```js
const toString = (number, alphabet) => {
  let result = "";
  while (number) {
      const digit = number%alphabet.length;
      number = (number/alphabet.length)|0;
      result = alphabet[digit] + result;
  }
  return result || alphabet[0]; 
}

//////////////////// For the opposite, you can use this:

const fromStringBuilder = (alphabet) => {
  const alphabetKeys = {};
  for (let i = 0; i < alphabet.length; i++) {
    alphabetKeys[alphabet[i]] = i;
  }

  return (string) => {
    return [...string].reduce((a,v) => a * alphabet.length + alphabetKeys[v],0);
  }
}

//////////////////// Here you have example usage:

toAlphabet = (number) => toString(number, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-')
fromAlphabet = fromStringBuilder('abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-')

console.log(fromAlphabet("3+")) // 1138
console.log(toAlphabet(1138)) // "3+"
console.log(toAlphabet(fromAlphabet("3+"))) // "3+"
```

Note: alphabet must be a string with at least two chars. Otherwise, the loop will be infinite.

Note 2: you have to pass the alphabet in the reverse order from your example to achieve the same exact output.

Comment: wondering if there is a way to reverse it, go from string back to integer

Comment: Just change `alphabet[digit]` with `alphabet[alphabet.length-digit-1]` but I think your order is a bit weird.

Comment: by reverse i mean `fromString(string, alphabet)`, not sure what to do with the `while(number)`

Comment: You can't use the same algorithm for reversing. You'll need a hash table in order to do the opposite.

Answer (score 0):

This works for `any` base higher than 2. All you have to do is populate the `keys` array, while the `base` is calculated by the `number of keys`.

The output of `toString(123, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-')` would be `dj`.

The output of `fromString('dj', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-')` would be `123`.

Run the snippet at the bottom of the code to see.

This is the code:

```js
// Converts a string back to it's original number form
function fromString(string, keys)
{
  var base = keys.length;
  var value = 0;
  
  if(base >= 2)
    for(var i=0; i<string.length; i++)
    {
        if(keys.indexOf(string[i]) != -1) value += keys.indexOf(string[i])*Math.pow(base,string.length - i - 1);
        else return 'Invalid code.';
    }
    return value;
}

// Converts a number from decimal base to base of keys.length
// also, it assumes you enter correct data
function toString(number, keys)
{
  var ready = false;
  var base = keys.length;
  var result = [];
  
  if(base >= 2)
    while(true)
    {
      result.unshift(keys[number % base]);
      number = Math.floor(number/base);
      if(number < 1) break;
    }
    return result.join('');
}

// Function that handles events on button click
function encryptDecrypt()
{
    var keys = document.getElementById('getTheKeys').value.split('');
    var encrypt = document.getElementById('encrypt').value;
    var encrypted = document.getElementById('encrypted');
    var decrypt = document.getElementById('decrypt').value;
    var decrypted = document.getElementById('decrypted');
    
    if(keys != '' && keys.length > 1)
    {
        if(encrypt != '' && parseInt(encrypt)) encrypted.value = toString(parseInt(encrypt), keys);
        if(decrypt != '') decrypted.value = fromString(decrypt, keys);
    }
}
```

```css
.giveMeSomeSpace
{
  padding-left:47px;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tr>
    <td colspan="2"><label for="getTheKeys">Enter the key string: </label><input type="text" id="getTheKeys" value="abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-" size="53"/></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="encrypt">Encrypt: </label><input type="text" id="encrypt" value="" placeholder="Enter a number"/></td>
    <td class="giveMeSomeSpace"><label for="encrypted">Encrypted: </label><input type="text" id="encrypted" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  <tr>
  <tr>
    <td><label for="decrypt">Decrypt: </label><input type="text" id="decrypt" value="" placeholder="Enter a key combination"/></td>
    <td class="giveMeSomeSpace"><label for="decrypted">Decrypted: </label><input type="text" id="decrypted" value="" readonly="readonly" /></td>
  <tr>
</table>

<input type="button" id="checkNow" value="Go" onclick="encryptDecrypt();" />
```

Answer (score 0):

Let's make a simple function for base 10 to base N.

```js
function b102bN (n,b, r = []){
  var getNumeral = d => d < 10 ? d : String.fromCharCode(d+87);
  
  return n ? (r.unshift(getNumeral(n%b)), b102bN(~~(n/b), b, r)) : r.join("");
}

console.log(b102bN(123,36));
console.log(b102bN(1453,40)); // obviously base 40 requires interesting characters as numerals
```