# How to generate a fixed-length code from a set of integers of a specific bit count in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, bit-manipulation, radix

*[Generate string from integer with arbitrary base in JavaScript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47895279/generate-string-from-integer-with-arbitrary-base-in-javascript)* received the following answer:

```js
function parseInt(value, code) {
    return [...value].reduce((r, a) => r * code.length + code.indexOf(a), 0);
}

function toString(value, code) {
    var digit,
        radix= code.length,
        result = '';

    do {
        digit = value % radix;
        result = code[digit] + result;
        value = Math.floor(value / radix);
    } while (value)

    return result;
}

console.log(parseInt('dj', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(toString(123, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(parseInt('a', 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
console.log(toString(0, 'abcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz0123456789+-'));
```

I am interested something slightly different. Whereas this will generate the shortest code for the number, I would like to now generate a constant-length code based on the number of *bits*. I am not sure if this is also a complex radix solution as well.

Say I want to generate 8-bit codes using a 16-character alphabet. That means I should be able to take the first 4 bits to select 1 character, and the next 4 bits to select the second character. So I might end up with `MV` if my 16 character set was `ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ`. Likewise if I had a 16-bit range, I would have 4 character code, and 32-bit range would be an 8-character code. So calling `code32(1, 'ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ')` would give an 8 letter code, while `code8(1, 'ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ')` would give a 2 digit code.

How could that be implemented in JavaScript? Something along these lines?

```
 code8(i, alpha) // 0 to 255 it accepts
 code16(i, alpha) // 0 to 65535 it accepts
 code32(i, alpha) // 0 to 2^32-1 it accepts
```

Likewise, how would you get the string code back into the original number (or bit sequence)?

Comment: So you're asking how to *pad* the `toString` result so it gives a fixed length output?

Comment: Is that what I'm asking? Haha I am not sure.

Comment: I keep imagining it is going to read 4 bits at a time, so an algorithm that does that and selects from the alphabet.

Comment: Well, that's what the `do...while` loop does. "4 bits at a time" is how `radix` is used in that loop, and "selects from the alphabet" is done with `code[digit]`. You just want to change the `while` loop into a `for` loop so it runs a fixed number of times, and control the parameters so that you only allow alphabet lengths that are a power of 2.

Comment: I can't tell what that will look like, does that literally mean I just pad the above radix solution?

Comment: Either you change to `while` loop to a `for` loop (making one iteration per desired output character), or you left-pad with the first character of the code (much like we can left-pad decimal numbers with zeroes). Either way the result is the same.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This really comes down to changing `toString` so that:

- It only accepts a code that has a length of a power of 2
- It pads the result to a given number of "digits" (characters)

The actual number of digits you would use for a 16 bit number depends on the size of the code. If the code has 16 characters, then it can cover for 4 bits, and so an output of 4 characters would be needed. If however the code has 4 characters, then the output would need 8 characters. You can have cases where the match is not exact, like when you would have a code with 8 characters. Then the output would need 6 characters.

Here I have highlighted the changes to the `toString` method. My personal preference is to also put the value as *last* parameter to `toString`.

```js
function toString(digitCount, code, value) { // <-- add argument digitCount
    // Perform a sanity check: code must have a length that is power of 2
    if (Math.log2(code.length) % 1) throw "code size not power of 2: " + code.length;
    var digit,
        radix = code.length,
        result = '';

    do {
        digit = value % radix;
        result = code[digit] + result;
        value = Math.floor(value / radix);
    } while (value)

    return result.padStart(digitCount, code[0]); // Pad to the desired output size
}

console.log(toString(4, 'abcdefghijklmnop',    123));
console.log(toString(4, 'abcdefghijklmnop',      0));
console.log(toString(4, 'abcdefghijklmnop', 0xFFFF));

// You could define some more specific functions

const code8 = (code, value) => toString(Math.ceil(8 / Math.log2(code.length)), code, value);
const code16 = (code, value) => toString(Math.ceil(16 / Math.log2(code.length)), code, value);  

console.log(code16('abcdefghijklmnop',    123));
console.log(code16('abcdefghijklmnop',      0));
console.log(code16('abcdefghijklmnop', 0xFFFF));

console.log(code8('abcdefghijklmnop',  123));
console.log(code8('abcdefghijklmnop',    0));
console.log(code8('abcdefghijklmnop', 0xFF));
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: I just noticed that you required a decoder as well. It is easy to implement a non-optimal version too, while an optimal one can be implemented via go through each letter and accumulate their value times their weighs.

Is this what you want? I tested this code for `bit=16` and `bit=8`, but when `bit=32` the count of codewords becomes too large and hangs the devtools of the browser. It's only a demonstrative code and may need optimization if need to be applied in practical use...

```js
function genCode(len, alpha){
    let tmp = [...alpha];
    for(let i = 1; i != len; ++i){
        const ttmp = [];
        tmp.forEach(te => {
            [...alpha].forEach(e => {
                ttmp.push(te + e);
            });
        });
        tmp = ttmp;
    }
    return tmp;
}

function code(bits, i, alpha){
    const len = Math.ceil(bits / Math.floor(Math.log2(alpha.length)));
    return genCode(len, alpha)[i];
}  

function decode(bits, c, alpha){
    const len = Math.ceil(bits / Math.floor(Math.log2(alpha.length)));
    const codes = genCode(len, alpha);
    return codes.indexOf(c);
}

console.log(code(16, 2, "ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ"));
console.log(decode(16, "AAAD", "ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ"));
console.log(code(8, 255, "ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ"));
console.log(decode(8, "ZZ", "ABDHNMOPQRSTUVYZ"));
```

Comment: I'm not sure this is it. What I'm thinking of should be high performing bit manipulation somehow.